# Variables appear undefined when accessed from within a function

Tags: javascript

My question basically grinds down to: why does this not work (variables data and i appear undefined when i click the button - look at the lines where variables x and y are declared)

```
        function fill_transfer_request_notification(data) {
            notification_list = document.querySelector('.live_notify_list');
            notification_list.innerHTML = "";
            template_notification = document.querySelector('#template_notification');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.unread_list.length; i++) {
                msg = data.unread_list[i];
                list_item = template_notification.content.cloneNode(true);
                list_item.querySelector('.notification_verb').textContent = data.unread_list[i].verb;
                list_item.querySelector('.notification_username_link').setAttribute('href',data.unread_list[i].data.href);
                list_item.querySelector('.notification_username_link').textContent = data.unread_list[i].data.username + " ";
                list_item.querySelector('.profile_img_req').setAttribute('src', data.unread_list[i].data.image_path);
                var x = data;
                var y = i;
                list_item.querySelector('.accept_transfer_button').onclick = function(){
                    window.location.href = data.unread_list[i].data.href;
                };
                notification_list.appendChild(list_item);
            }
        }
```

and this does work?

```
        function fill_transfer_request_notification(data) {
            notification_list = document.querySelector('.live_notify_list');
            notification_list.innerHTML = "";
            template_notification = document.querySelector('#template_notification');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.unread_list.length; i++) {
                msg = data.unread_list[i];
                list_item = template_notification.content.cloneNode(true);
                list_item.querySelector('.notification_verb').textContent = data.unread_list[i].verb;
                list_item.querySelector('.notification_username_link').setAttribute('href',data.unread_list[i].data.href);
                list_item.querySelector('.notification_username_link').textContent = data.unread_list[i].data.username + " ";
                list_item.querySelector('.profile_img_req').setAttribute('src', data.unread_list[i].data.image_path);
                var x = data;
                var y = i;
                list_item.querySelector('.accept_transfer_button').onclick = function(){
                    window.location.href = x.unread_list[y].data.href;
                };
                notification_list.appendChild(list_item);
            }
        }
```

Comment: data is passed to this function. It might be, you are not passing anything to this function

Comment: show your function call

Comment: you cannot access a variable inside a function you have to return it.